# How can I retrieve array data instead of dictionary?

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have `messages` child that including

```
- "Some key"
    - "messages"
        - "child by autoid"
            - "text": String
            - "sender": String
        - "child by autoid"
            - "text": String
            - "sender": String
    - "create_date": Date
```

I need to retrieve messages as Array without auto id. Can I do that?
I can't find the way to do it.

Now, I retrieve it to dictionary then map to array. but the problem is index changed while mapping. so how can I retrieve it to array?

Comment: How are you mapping to an array? what index is changed while you are doing it. What's wrong with the autoId? Can you show some code that demonstrates the issue?

Answer (score 1):

You can observe the `"messages"` child value, and then create an array of FIRDataSnapshot from the children.

```
let ref = FIRDatabase.database().reference().child("messages")
ref.observe(.value, with: snapshot in {
    // each snap in snapshots      
    if let snapshots = snapshot.children.allObjects as? [FIRDataSnapshot] {
        for snap in snapshots {
            // do things
        }
    }
})
```

Comment: Thanks Jen, But I also needed "create_date" (I have informations more than this). so I have to observe child above "messages" and "create_date".

Comment: Or I have to observe "childadded" both "messages" and "some key"?

Comment: Observing both is definitely an option, especially if the data isn't needed for one shared purpose. What is the relationship between "messages" and "create_date"? Do they need to be under the same key? Why can't "create_date" be under "messages"?

Comment: I have to explain more. The top of child is "Channels" > "autoid" > ("messages" : "owner" : "create_date").  I have "owner" that's using for keep who's owner of this chat channel. 1 user can have many channels. and "create_date" using for record when user start chat. I also keep "timestamp" in "messages" too. That's why I needed it there. If you have any suggestion or better solutions that would be great. :D Thanks